# TYPO3: crawler configuration record backend validation error

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I've installed the site crawler extension 9.2.2 on TYPO3 10.4.14. When trying to add Crawler Configuration the TYPO3 Backend validation throws an error, although the required field (checkbox) is checked.

Can this happen with misconfiguration of TYPO3 or Crawler or is it a bug that I must report?

[image: screenshot of the validation error]

Comment: This is already a known bug in the TYPO3 Crawler.
https://github.com/AOEpeople/crawler/issues/727 I'm still working on fixing the pipeline. You could help move this forward by testing the PR for the fix. https://github.com/AOEpeople/crawler/pull/730/files

Comment: Thx for the hint, "In tx_crawler_configuration.php line 75: Remove: 'eval' => 'required'," solved the issue, I added review and approved the changes, but have no write access to the repository, so automatic merging is blocked

Comment: There is now a new version of the TYPO3 Crawler released with a fix.

https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/crawler